# Open a popup windows with my own html/javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to open a popup window, but without given a link : just open it with some HTML and Javascript code (that I pass trought the function).

Tried with :

```
window.open($('.my_html').html(), "Booking", "width=950,height=680");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything or would you like us to do your work for you?

Comment: Yeah of course. Added an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
writeConsole('Hello from JavaScript!');
function writeConsole(content) {
 top.consoleRef=window.open('','myconsole','width=350,height=250');
 top.consoleRef.document.write(content)
 top.consoleRef.document.close()
}
```

[Source](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/writingt.htm)

Comment: It seems to work. But how can I include also the css attribute? :)

Comment: Ok done. I resolve it including the <head></head> element with the reference of the css (it will load it dinamically). It's nice :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var popup = window.open(#mySettings#);
```

and then

```
popup.document.write('#myHTML#');
```

Comment: yeah, but what will be `#mySettings#`? In fact it gets a uri, not an "html source"

Comment: Just leave it (the URI) blank.

Answer (score 2):

```
function openpopup(content){ 
    winpops=window.open('',"test","fullscreen=no,toolbar=yes,status=yes, " +
    "menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,directories=yes,location=yes, " +
    "width=500,height=400,left=100,top=100,screenX=100,screenY=100");
    winpops.document.write(content);
} 
openpopup('<h1>This is some test content</h1>');
```

You can call function on any event, and supply content you want to show.

Comment: He says he doesn't want to show a URL. He wants to write custom code to that window.

Comment: I have corrected it. At first I thought he doesn`t want to open it on a link click.

Answer (score 1):

do you have to use browser popups? They're annoying and can be blocked by ad-blockers.

Why not do it as modal windows instead? like this: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/

or the jQuery plugin jqModal.

Comment: in fact what I need is to print that "popup" (later), so I think windows.print will fail with your method...

Comment: you can add a print style or styleshhet along with the modal to hide everything except the modal.

Comment: will be ok for a simple site, not with tons of elements :) I'm ok with popup, thank you